# WCF known types, not works

Tags: wcf, types

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DBReq))]
public interface IDAService
{


[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IDataParameterCollection))]
public class DBReq : DBAccess
{

    [DataMember]
    public IDataParameterCollection DataParams
    {
    ...
```

Why does DataParams deserialize to type of Object on my client side?

Comment: If i am not wrong KnownTypes are applicalbe to server side for the framework to identify that the incoming message can be deserialized to a specific type can happen when the request is recieved by a service so that the deserialization takes place and does not throw an bad request exception

Answer (score 1):

Your `[KnownType(typeof(IDataParameterCollection))]` is not correct. You should pass the implementing types to the KnownType attribute.

For example

```
public class MyType : IDataParameterCollection {...}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyType))]
public class DBReq : DBAccess
{

    [DataMember]
    public IDataParameterCollection DataParams
    {
    ...
```

Comment: public class DataParameterCollection : ArrayList,IDataParameterCollection  --------- There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:req. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Elco.DataAccess.DataParameterCollection' with data contract name 'ArrayOfanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.